# AppxManifest - difference between identity and mp:PhoneIdentity

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

When I create an appx app with VS2013 for Windows Phone, the AppxManifest.xml contains the following two entries:

```
<Identity Name="Something.Arbitrary" Publisher="CN=GUID-GUID-GUID" Version="1.0.0.0" />

<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="5fbbac69-e356-41ee-af0d-0aab0eb96d7c" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
```

What is the difference between the two Identity Name and PhoneIdentity values?

Comment: Windows and Windows Phone use the same AppX package file, but the two Stores are still different. So this is a way of putting Windows Phone Store metadata into the file that was originally designed for the Windows Store. You can associate a Phone app with a Windows app in the Store so that users can buy once and download in both places, but behind the scenes they're still separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mp:PhoneIdentity is used, if you update your app coming from an older version, e.g. Windows Phone 8.0.

With newer versions, like 8.1 Phone or 8.1 Universal Apps, it creates a new type of application binary and it can't create a link to the old store data. E.g.: If you then test your IAPs, your app won't find the IAP items.

This is done with the values PhoneProductId and PhonePublisherId.

Quoting the docs ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Dn642081%28v=VS.105%29.aspx ):

> The PhoneProductID and PhonePublisherID attributes of the
>   mp:PhoneIdentity element in the Package.appxmanifest file are
>   available to enable these upgrade scenarios. These attributes map to
>   the ProductID and PublisherID attributes of the published Windows
>   Phone 8 app.